# (Computational fluid dynamics) Problem with arrays. Why is my C program outputting -1.#IND00

Tags: arrays, c, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I have a problem with a program i'm writing in C that solves the 1D linear convection equation. Basically i have initialized an two arrays. The first array (u0_array) is an array of ones with the arrays elements set equal to two over the interval or 0.5 < x < 1. The second array (usol_array) serves as a temporary array that the result or solution will be stored in.

**The problem i am running into is the nested for loop at the end of my code**. This loop applies the update equation required to calculate the next point, to each element in the array. When i run my script and try to print the results the output i get is just -1.IND00 for each iteration of the loop. (I am following Matlab style pseudo code which i also have attached below) I'm very new with C so my inexperience shows. I don't know why this is happening. If anyone could suggest a possible fix to this i would be very grateful. I have attached my code so far below with a few comments so you can follow my thought process. I have also attached the Matlab style pseudo code i'm followed.

```
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <time.h>


int main ( )
{
    //eqyation to be solved 1D linear convection -- du/dt + c(du/dx) = 0
    //initial conditions u(x,0) = u0(x)

    //after discretisation using forward difference time and backward differemce space
    //update equation becomes u[i] = u0[i] - c * dt/dx * (u0[i] - u[i - 1]);


    int nx = 41; //num of grid points

    int dx = 2 / (nx - 1); //magnitude of the spacing between grid points

    int nt = 25;//nt is the number of timesteps

    double dt = 0.25; //the amount of time each timestep covers

    int c = 1;  //assume wavespeed


    //set up our initial conditions. The initial velocity u_0
    //is 2 across the interval of 0.5 <x < 1 and u_0 = 1 everywhere else.
    //we will define an array of ones
    double* u0_array = (double*)calloc(nx, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        u0_array[i] = 1;
    }

    // set u = 2 between 0.5 and 1 as per initial conditions
    //note 0.5/dx = 10, 1/dx+1 = 21
    for (int i = 10; i < 21; i++)
    {
        u0_array[i] = 2;
        //printf("%f, ", u0_array[i]);
    }

    //make a temporary array that allows us to store the solution
    double* usol_array = (double*)calloc(nx, sizeof(double));


    //apply numerical scheme forward difference in
    //time an backward difference in space
    for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++)
    {
        //first loop iterates through each time step
        usol_array[i] = u0_array[i];
        //printf("%f", usol_array[i]);
        

        //MY CODE WORKS FINE AS I WANT UP TO THIS LOOP
        //second array iterates through each grid point for that time step and applies
        //the update equation
        for (int j = 1; j < nx - 1; j++)
        {
            u0_array[j] = usol_array[j] - c * dt/dx * (usol_array[j] - usol_array[j - 1]);
            printf("%f, ", u0_array[j]);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For reference also the pseudo code i am following is attached below
[1D linear convection pseudo Code (Matlab Style)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7uf.png)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of integer division, use FP math.
This avoid the later division by 0 and *-1.#IND00*

```
// int dx = 2 / (nx - 1);   quotient is 0.
double dx = 2.0 / (nx - 1);
```

---

OP's code does not match comment

```
// u[i] = u0[i] - c * dt/dx * (u0[i] - u[i - 1]
u0_array[j] = usol_array[j] - c * dt/dx * (usol_array[j] - usol_array[j - 1]);
```

Easier to see if the redundant `_array` removed.

```
//                                     v correct?
// u[i] = u0[i] - c * dt/dx * (u0[i] - u[i - 1]
u0[j] = usol[j] - c * dt/dx * (usol[j] - usol[j - 1]);
//                                       ^^^^ Correct?
```

Comment: hiya. Thank you this got rid of the -1.#IND00 problem. Now the output is a bit bazzar with really long double numbers but its a step in the right direction nonetheless. Thank you very much. I f you have any other suggestions that would be great.

Comment: @mcgrane5  Tip: 1) It is more informative to print FP values with `"%e"` or `"%g"` than `"%f"` - especially when debugging. 2) enable all warnings.  3) When allocating use `ptr = calloc(n, sizeof *ptr);` idiom (Notice no types in that line)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is in matlab terms

```matlab
for i = 1:nt
    usol = u0
    u0(2:nx) = usol(2:nx) - c*dt/dx*(usol(2:nx)-usol(1:nx-1))
end%for
```

This means that you have 2 inner loops over the space dimension, one for each of the two vector operations. These two separate loops have to be explicit in the C code

```c
    //apply numerical scheme forward difference in
    //time an backward difference in space
    for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        //first loop iterates through each time step
        for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++) {
            usol_array[j] = u0_array[j];
            //printf("%f", usol_array[i]);
        } 
        

        //second loop iterates through each grid point for that time step 
        //and applies the update equation
        for (int j = 1; j < nx; j++)
        {
            u0_array[j] = usol_array[j] - c * dt/dx * (usol_array[j] - usol_array[j - 1]);
            printf("%f, ", u0_array[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I rearranged my loops as by your code above but Its still not working as i expect. I have the same problem coded out in python and it works as i want.  Ill continue to try debug it. thank you for your contribution though

Comment: hi there, just to let you know and perhaps anyone else who has a similar problem with a program of the same type i figured out the bug. I replaced the line usol_array[ i ] = u0_array[ i ] with memcpy( usol_array,  u0_array, nx * sizeof(double) ) to copy the arrays contents that way and the program runs as expected. Thank you for all your help also